Where can I find documentation for the raw syscalls?
I would like to use the raw solana syscalls in unsafe blocks in my onchain program similar to how the SDK does it.
However, it's a bit hard to figure out what each (C-style) argument means without any documentation. For example, I had to compare the #[cfg(target_os = "solana") implementation for alt_bn128_multiplication against the #[cfg(not(target_os = "solana")) implementation to figure out that sol_alt_bn128_group_op syscall's 2nd argument is a 96 byte array where [0..64] is the uncompressed curve point in big-endian (x-coordinate being [0..32], y-coordinate being [32..64]) while [64..96] is the 256-bit scalar in big-endian.
Is there a place where all these syscalls are documented?

Reading the source code is going to be your best option unfortunately. The concept is to eventually document all syscalls in various SIMDs, but the SIMDs are mostly being done for new changes only. For example, here's a SIMD about alt bn128's error codes: https://github.com/solana-foundation/solana-improvement-documents/blob/9359c71565c91f5ee9b4d5dd103df5d65ba26d68/proposals/0129-alt-bn128-simplified-error-code.md
The actual syscall implementations can be found under programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls. For example, here's the implementation for alt bn128: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/a99c916b36bcee8ca2f8568b14db3d42ff79edb1/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/mod.rs#L1563
